# How to change MySQL instance used by MySQL Connector/C++ ?

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I have installed 64 bit MySQL Connector/C++ and tested database connection via [tutorial code](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html). There are two instances of MySQL installed on the machine as below.

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.21, for Win64 (x86_64) 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for Win32 (x86)
```

Connector is using 32 bit version of MySQL which I need to change to 64 bit version. Is there a way of doing this ?

I added ports as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-windows-services.html) and tried to use port of 64 bit version but it did not work.